# Shipping modules does not update rate on zip code changes in guest-checkout page Magento 2 production mode

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, shipping, shipping-methods

Preconditions

1. Magento 2.0.4 install
2. Cart page and checkout page

Steps to reproduce:

```
1. Put any product inside your cart
2. Open cart page or checkout page
3. input zipCode to calculate tax for shipping
```

Expected result
Module should update the rate for shipping each time I change the zip code.

Actual result:
Nothing happens, the value doesn't appear.

**It's working perfectly on developer mode**, **but not in production mode** when we update or change zip-code it will do nothing. not even going to validation, no errors.

In developer mode it does validation and sends AJAX request on this url , and everything goes fine.
/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/estimate-shipping-methods

Any help will thankful of you.

> Update: now its work on production mode too if I turn off this things
>   from admin->stores->configuration->advance->developer Merge JavaScript
>   Files No Enable Javascript Bundling  No Minify JavaScript Files NO

Any help, advice?

Comment: Are you entering valid zip code magento have set valid zip code based on county, that display warning yellow message, and there is display any error in browser console ?

Comment: yes the are valid zip code. even i said in developer mode its working perfectly. but not in production mode. in production mode no validation are applying and no ajax request getting fire. this problem only on production mode

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be comes in various way.

1. check for by turn off this things from

> admin->stores->configuration->advance->developer
>
> ```
>     Enable Javascript Bundling  No
>     Minify JavaScript Files NO
> ```

this issue is in my case: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13810

2. If you made some custom code for it go throw 
   https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8240

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13430